# How to tell which tests take the most time in jasmine?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I noticed that the whole suite of Jasmine tests started taking more time that I would like, but I'm not sure, which ones actually cause the delay. Is there a way to find that out without running each test individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic `ConsoleReporter` only reports the time elapsed for all the tests, but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js) of it you will see it's quite easy to modify to add the elapsed time for each spec. Basically what you need to do is to log the time a spec start when the function `reportSpecStarting` (that's just before a spec starts to run) is called and output the difference when the function `reportSpecResults` (that's just after a spec has finished running).

So if you modified the [`ConsoleReporter`](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js) with this, it would output you the name of each specification with their elapsed time :

```
this.reportSpecStarting = function() {
    this.specStartingTime = this.now();
};

this.reportSpecResults = function(spec) {
    var results = spec.results();

    print(results.description + " ");

    if (results.skipped) {
        yellowStar();
    } else if (results.passed()) {
        greenDot();
    } else {
        redF();
    }

    print(" (" + (this.now() - this.specStartingTime) + "ms)");
    newline();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using Jasmines HTMLReporter?  (down towards the bottom)
http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/

hmmm.. maybe you can loop it so each file is executed individually? (not the best answer :( )
http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/07/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-bdd-style-unit-tests-with-jasmine-node-sprinkled-with-some-should/

Comment: Apparently `jasmine-node` contains no HTMLReporter - only terminal ones